# Issue on Padding - Margin

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please take a look at this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NkJPt/embedded/result/) and let me know why there is white space between Purple and Yellow divs? I tried every thing like setting:

```
*{padding:0; margin:0;}
```

or setting left right margins of all divs to 0 but that space still there! Thanks

Comment: You should make sure that there is nothing (even return character) between the 2 divs.

Comment: Thanks king king but can you please let me know what exactly you mean ? what is return character?

Comment: for example, you type the closing tag `</div>` of the first `div`, then you hit `Enter`, then you type the second `div`, what you should do is don't hit Enter like so, just type the second div right after the first like this `<div>...</div><div>...</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the page : http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/less/mixins.less

```
.col-md-1 {
width: 8.33333333%;
}
```

just change your width

```
width: 8.33333333%;
```

to

```
width: inherit;
```

Comment: Hi airi , can you please let me know I should change width of what?

Comment: the purple width just change it to inherit

Comment: <div class="col-md-1" id="cart">  <-- your css class for col-md-1 change it to inherit

Comment: Thanks airi, it works now BUT can you please let me know why there is still scroller (horizontal) in the page?

Comment: btw.. u not mention any of scroller in your questions

Comment: I tought it is because of that space

Comment: add this in your tab to hide the scroller : width: 1300px;

Comment: <div id="tabs" style="height: 900px;width: 1300px;">